# how to parse multivalued field from URL query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have a URL of form `http://www.example.com?foo=one&foo=two`

I want to get an array of values `['one', 'two']` for `foo`, but `params[:foo]` only returns the first value.

I know that if I used `foo[]` instead of `foo` in the URL, then `params[:foo]` would give me the desired array.

However, I want to avoid changing the structure of the URL if possible, since its form is provided as a spec to a client application. is there a good way to get all the values without changing the parameter name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the default Ruby CGI module to parse the query string in a Rails controller like so:

```
params = CGI.parse(request.query_string)
```

This will give you what you want, but note that you won't get any of Rails other extensions to query string parsing, such as using `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so you will have to us String rather than Symbol keys.

Also, I don't believe you can set params like that with a single line and overwrite the default rails params contents.  Depending on how widespread you want this change, you may need to monkey patch or hack the internals a little bit.  However the expeditious thing if you wanted a global change would be to put this in a before filter in `application.rb` and use a new instance var like `@raw_params`

Comment: works like a charm, thanks. I just needed it in a single place in one controller, so I didn't even need to muck with params.

Answer (score 3):

I like the CGI.parse(request.query_string) solution mentioned in another answer. You could do this to merge the custom parsed query string into params:

```
params.merge!(CGI.parse(request.query_string).symbolize_keys)
```

Comment: Automatically symbolizing will open yourself up for a DoS attack on your application. Ruby never garbage collects Symbol instances, thus they stay around in memory, doing nothing, until the app is rebooted.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil - Do you have a link that explains this issue in more detail?  Is it still a concern in Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 3?

Comment: @MattHuggins - See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7791. And the issue is supposed to be solved in 2.2.